# Rails named_scope inheritance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, activerecord, named-scope

I'm trying to generalize some of my models by providing a common base model to inherit from that contains some mutual named_scope declarations and a filter method that activates that search for simpler querying on the controller side. This appears to be working when I run it in the console, but fails when in the controller:

```
# in the base model
class GenericModel < ActiveRecord::Base

  named_scope :by_name, lambda { |name|
    ( name.blank? ) ? {} : { :conditions => [ "#{self.table_name}.name like ?", "%#{name}%" ] }
  }

  def filter(params)
    res = []
    res = self.by_name( (params[:name] or '') ) if params[:name]
    return res
  end

end

class MyModel < GenericModel
  set_table_name 'my_models'
end

# works in in console!
>> params = { :name => 'jimmy' }
>> MyModel.filter(params)
=> [ <#MyModel ...>, ... ]
nil

# fails in controller
@model = MyModel.filter(params)

# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql::Error Unknown column 'generic_models.name' in where clause...)
```

Apparently the parent class' named_scope is being called when in rails, but works fine in rails console. Any ideas how to mend this? thanks.

Comment: Not that this solves your problem, but you should be using module mixins instead of inheritance for this. Inheritance is intended for subclasses that represent a "type" of the parent class.

Comment: Actually, @Beerlington, that might solve the OP's problem, :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a bit of a train-wreck because of the way ActiveRecord is trying to interpret what you're saying. Generally the first class derived from ActiveRecord::Base is used to define what the base table name is, and sub-classes of that are defined to use Single Table Inheritance (STI) by default. You're working around this by using `set_table_name` but, as is often the case, while it's possible to go against the grain in Rails, things often get messy.

You should be able to do this a lot more cleanly using a mixin as suggested by Beerlington.

```
module ByNameExtension
  def self.extended(base)
    # This method is called when a class extends with this module

    base.send(:scope, :by_name, lambda { |name|
      name.blank? ? nil : where("#{self.table_name}.name LIKE ?", "%#{name}%")
    })
  end

  def filter(params)
    params[:name].present? ? self.by_name(params[:name]) : [ ]
  end
end

class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Load in class-level methods from module ByNameExtension
  extend ByNameExtension
end
```

You should be able to keep your extensions contained to that module. If you want to clean this up even further, write an initializer that defines a method like `scoped_by_name` for ActiveRecord::Base that triggers this behavior:

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
  def scoped_by_name
    extend ByNameExtension
  end
end
```

Then you can tag all classes that require this:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  scoped_by_name
end
```

Comment: This look great.  Where do you put the initializer (ActiveRecord::Base) code file?

Comment: Unless you've made a proper gem or plugin, usually `config/initializers` is a good place.